# Or/ | statement in R

Tags: r

Belows is me code for selecting attribute "Airline" equal to "CX", "GA", "HX" or "RI" only.

```
Result <- Result[which(Result$Airline == "CX" | Result$Airline == "GA" | 
                         Result$Airline == "HX" | Result$Airline == "RI"),]
```

I would like to ask whether there is something like `OR(Result$Airline, c("CX","GA","HX","RI"))` in R?

Thanks for your gentle help.

Comment: `%in%` should do the trick in this case: `Result[Result$Airline%in%c('CX','GA','HX','RI'),]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Result <- Result[which(Result$Airline %in% c( "CX","GA","HX","RI"),]
```

Comment: Note also that `which` can be dropped (as suggested by @plannapus), since `%in%` will return a logical vector that can be used for subsetting `Result`.

Comment: @jbaums that's good to know. I will use it the way you suggest in the future. Thanks!

Comment: A bit of an aside, but this can be particularly important when attempting to remove elements with negative indexing. For example we might expect `LETTERS[-which(LETTERS %in% 1:3)]` to return all letters, but it returns `character(0)` since no `LETTERS` appear in `1:3`. Instead we should negate the logical vector `LETTERS[!LETTERS %in% 1:3]` (more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16047825/489704)).