# find indexes in R by not using `which`

Tags: r

Is there a faster way to search for indices rather than **`which %in%`** R.

I am having a statement which I need to execute but its taking a lot of time.

statement:

```
total_authors<-paper_author$author_id[which(paper_author$paper_id%in%paper_author$paper_id[which(paper_author$author_id%in%data_authors[i])])]
```

How can this be done in a faster manner?

Comment: Are you sure that this indexing is the slow part of your code?

Comment: my code is very running very slow and it mainly uses which statements so i thought that it could be due to which statements

Answer (score 1):

<del>Don't call `which`.  R accepts logical vectors as indices, so the call is superfluous.</del>
In light of sgibb's comment, you can keep `which` if you are sure that you will also get at least one match.  (If there are no matches, then `which` returns an empty vector and you get everything instead of nothing. See [Unexpected behavior using -which() in R when the search term is not found](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16047825/134830).)

Secondly, the code looks a little cleaner if you use `with`.

Thirdly, I think you want a single index with `&` rather than a double index.

```
total_authors <- with(
  paper_author,
  author_id[paper_id %in% paper_id & author_id %in% data_authors[i]
)
```

Comment: *Don't call `which`* is surprisingly not faster than `which`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510778/why-is-subsetting-on-a-logical-type-slower-than-subetting-on-numeric-type

Comment: @sgibb it's dangerous to generalised from that one case, and general you should avoid performance optimisation in favour of clear code (unless it's obvious that they reduce a bottleneck)